# How can i read usb disk volumn label in a embedded linux?

Tags: linux, usb

It's possible to read usb disk volumn label in a embedded linux when a usb flash plugin on? I know it's easy to get volumn label on pc, but in embedded linux I can not find the "/dev/disk" directory, I've no idea about how to get it, so any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel requires support for the relevant FS. use `blkid` or if it's not available, I suggest using `strace` or looking in the source code to find out what IOCTL/syscalls are involved.